# No Instance of overloaded function vector of structs

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I creating a project from college where I have to recreate the Scrabble Junior game to a console Game, but I've got a problem and i question in my code.

Firstly, I've got an error in my code saying :

```
"no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=Board::Word, _Alloc=std::allocator<Board::Word>]" matches the argument list                      
argument types are: (Board::Word)
object type is: std::vector<Board::Word, std::allocator<Board::Word>>
```

The struct Word is this one:

```
struct Word {
    int row;
    int column;
    char orientation;
    int tilesadded = 0; //starts at 0
    int wordlength;
    bool completed = false;
    int currentletterpositiontoAdd[2]; //array to hold the coordenates of the next tile to be added
    std::string name;
};
```

This struct basically stores every word and it's position in the board

And then I have also a vector storing every word struct: `std::vector <Word> words;`

The code that builds this struct is the following (because I get from a file every word and position to the board):

```
void Board::GetBoard()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    std::string filename, input;
    std::cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::cout << "What is the directory of the board file? (.txt is added for you) -> ";
    while (std::getline(std::cin, filename))
    {
        file.open(filename + ".txt");
        if (!file.is_open())
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            file.clear();
            RED;
            std::cerr << "Error reading file." << std::endl;
            WHITE;
            std::cout << "What is the directory of the board file? (.txt is added for you) -> ";
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    while (std::getline(file, input))
    {
        if ((int)input[0] == 49 || (int)input[0] == 50)
        { //this means that its the first line of the file and the first character is either 1 or 2
            boardSize = stoi(input.substr(0, 2));
        }
        else
        {
            std::string nametoCat;
            Word word;
            word.row = input[0] - 'A' + 1; //calculation of the position on the board using ascii code ex: input[0] = C  so: 'C' -'A' + 1 = 3   row -> 3
            word.column = input[1] - 'a' + 1; //calculation of the position on the board using ascii code ex: input[1] = e  so: 'e' -'a' + 1 = 5   column -> 5
            word.orientation = input[3];
            word.currentletterpositiontoAdd[0] = word.row;
            word.currentletterpositiontoAdd[1] = word.column;
            for (int x = 5; x < 1000000000; x++)
            { //for loop to check the name ending and build a string with the name
                if (input[x] == '\0')
                    break;
                else
                    nametoCat += input[x];
            }
            word.name = nametoCat;
            word.wordlength = word.name.size(); //storing the word length to use later to check if word is completed in board
            words.push_back(word);
        }
    }
}
```

The file looks like this:

```
15 x 15
Ak H EGGS
Bg H BUZZ
Ca H MUSIC
Cm H ARM
...
```

And secondly, I would like to make the code look more "clean" and understandable and remove that `1000000000` from: `for (int x = 5; x < 1000000000; x++)` and do it another way, but i can't find a solution. Because this 1000000000 looks like a magic number and not a number that would always work, for example, wouldn't work with a word of size 1000000001 (unlikely but possible).

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide full error message, it should contain additional information. For your second question, what is the type of `input`?

Comment: It's not obvious to me what the error is. Of course you should be able to push_back a Word to a vector of Words. Could you gave a bit more context. Like where your words vector is declared and how that relates to the code you've posted.

Comment: input is a string

Comment: the vector is declared in the class, and the push_back happens in the methods

Comment: So, if I'm reading it right you want `nametoCat = input.substr(5);`

Comment: @lxasdwqe So the code above is a method of your class? Could you show the complete method.

Comment: i didn't know we could only use a argument in substr() to indicate position. Thanks!

Comment: @john ill edit the post

Comment: @lxasdwqe Yes, `input.substr(5)` means from the fifth position to the end of the `input` string. It would be an error though if `input` was smaller than five characters.

Comment: I don't understand why but i'ts not give error anymore in vector push_back when i correct it to input.substr(5)

Comment: `(int)input[0] == 49 || (int)input[0] == 50)` Instead, you should do `input[0] == '1' || input[0] == '2'` Then you won't need the explanatory comment either. Your code will just document itself.

Comment: `const int not_a_magic_number = 1000000000;`

Comment: @lxasdwqe It's not giving an error for me either, http://cpp.sh/9rbwz , even without the change to substr.

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: The error is weird. Present a [mcve]. From your tale that the error goes away when you change some other line, it sounds like you weren't building the file you thought you were ;)

Comment: i thought it was a visual studio bug because code was still building and running normally, but would always appear the error message